# Proper AngularJS way to handle routing within the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

What's the preferred way to handle routing after a controller is done performing a task? In my specific scenario, I have a route that goes to a "create a new record" page. On clicking the submit button, the controller does its thing. I know it's bad practice to directly do a `$location.path()` call from inside the controller, so what's the preferred way to tell my view to go to a new location?

View:

```
<section ng-controller="AssignmentController">
  <h3>New Assignment</h1>
  <form name="assignments_new">
    <label for="description">Description</label> <input name="description" id="description" ng-model="assignment.description" type="text" ng-maxlength="100" placeholder="Short description of project" />
    <button class="button button-mini button-primary" ng-click="createAssignment()">Create</button>
    <button class="button button-mini" cancel>Cancel</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
$app.controller('AssignmentController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $scope.assignment = {
    description: null
  }

  $scope.createAssignment = function() {
    $http.post('/hooks/assignments_new.php', $scope.assignment).success(function(data) {
      if (data.success) { 
        // Tell the view to redirect back to /assignments
      } else {    
      }
    }).error(function(data)) {
    }
  }
});
```

I have years of javascript experience, but this is my first go with Angular. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is `$location.path()` deemed bad practice? That is exactly what I would use here. Or maybe modularize it as a navigation service with your common routes which you then inject and call from your controllers.

Comment: `I know it's bad practice to directly do a $location.path() call from inside the controller` - where'd you hear that? If that's true, I have a lot of code to change

Comment: Me three. Even my ProAngularJs book just uses location.path.

Comment: From the `$location` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) _"Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser."_ so I dont think it is a bad practice

Comment: Maybe I'm taking the "keep the UI out of the controllers" too seriously, then. I'm basing the assumption on the fact that I was encourage early on to not mess around with the DOM directly in the controller and to instead use things like `no-show` and `ng-disabled` to remotely affect the front-end. Maybe that doesn't apply here, though.

Comment: @PatrickEvans That's certainly true. If this is considered appropriate I'm more than happy to use it. Just trying to make sure I learn the "right way" to do things here. Appreciate the guidance!

Comment: That means you shouldn't do like `document.getElementId("someid").remove()`, you should use one of the angular services/directives to do that. Plus `$location` is an angular service so you are not really messing with the DOM outside of angular

Comment: @andy I'd still suggest you put your $location methods in your own service if you are planning on building a large app, things can get complicated with urls...

Comment: @AlexC That's the concern I had. This particular app isn't large at all, but I wasn't sure if there was a "better way" to handle routing for a larger app. I'll go with direct `$location` calls for this app but keep the advice in mind for future projects.